# Почему может не работать form accept?

Tags: html, form

```
 <form action="uploadava.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/*,image/jpeg" >
      <input type="file" name="filename"><br> 
      <input type="submit" value="Загрузить"><br>
      </form>
```

accept="image/*,image/jpeg"
всеравно предлагает выбор любого файла.
Может есть какое-то другое средство?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что атрибут `accept` необходимо использовать у `input`, поддерживается не всеми браузерами, поэтому лучше воспользоваться JS

```
<input accept="audio/*|video/*|image/*|MIME_type" />
```

Подробности [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp).